# Why does regex fail to match quotes?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, unicode

In my wordpress post contents, I have a line `[yu_TOC title="Short Stories"]`. I am trying to match it with

```
preg_match('/\[yu_TOC title=\"(.*?)\"\s*\]/', $content[0], $matchedTitle);
```

I have printed out the line I wanted to match using `error_log(substr($content, 0, 1000));`.

The output (relevant part of it) is `[yu_TOC title=&#8221;Short Stories&#8221;]</p>`

Is it expected that the quotes have changed from `"` to `&#8221;`?

Why does not my pattern match the line that should be matched?

How to fix it?

*Update: I have tried to replace []s with {}s, still the same issue.*

Comment: It looks like the content is encoded with [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or something similar before it is passed to preg_match.

Comment: @MichalHynčica  Yes, I have noticed that much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those quotes have changed and you also want to match the encoded version you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either one of them in a capturing group and then use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` for the same match as the accompanying closing match.

Your value is in the second capturing group as the first group is used for the backreference.

```
\[yu_TOC title=("|&#8221;)(.*?)\1\s*\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCzm3N/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/oY8aC)

**Note** that you don't have to escape `"`

For example

```
$content = ["[yu_TOC title=&#8221;Short Stories&#8221;]</p>"];
preg_match('/\[yu_TOC title=("|&#8221;)(.*?)\1\s*\]/', $content[0], $matchedTitle);
print_r($matchedTitle);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => [yu_TOC title=&#8221;Short Stories&#8221;]
    [1] => &#8221;
    [2] => Short Stories
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you know why the quotes have changed, is there any general rule when the characters change into their unicode equivalents?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any knowledge of wordpress itself so I am afraid I don't know the answer to that question.